# Getting errors while debugging android App.How to resolve this?

Tags: android, debugging, compiler-errors

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

logs :

08-25 15:12:45.610 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:45.667 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:45.668 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:47.040 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:47.055 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:48.345 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:48.351 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:49.879 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:49.885 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:50.611 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:50.668 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:50.668 666-701/? E/QCALOG: [MessageQ] ProcessNewMessage: [XT-CS] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
08-25 15:12:51.411 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:51.418 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:52.919 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:52.924 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed
08-25 15:12:54.594 16866-16888/? E/DPMJ: |DPM:NSRM:PLCY| NSRM Parser failed

Comment: share your log here

Comment: there are more error logs. Check all logs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to build.gradle and rebuild project again;

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```